# Count Days Student has Attended

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I'm trying to count up the days a student has attended class.

[image: database]

I need it to display the total attendance based on what `member_id` is logged in.

This is what I have so far:

```
$id_member = 3;
$query = "SELECT COUNT(attendance) AS day_at FROM day_attendance WHERE id_member=$id_member"; 
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($response);
$day_at = $row["day_at"];
echo $day_at;
```

It throws this error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /usr/www/user1/web/data/test.php on line 737`

Comment: You have `member_id` field in your table, not `id_member` as in your query. Closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misspelled the id column, should be `member_id` (as in your screen) and not `id_member` as in your sql query.

That's why `mysqli_fetch_array` print you a warning, because `mysqli_query` fail, and when it fail it returns a boolean (false). (Btw it's really bad to use the @ character)

Comment: Fixed it. I'm stupid. Why is it bad to use the @?

Comment: I mean it's a bah habit, because it remove error/warning when an error message can be usefull to help you to fix your code :)